# Third-party-reporting Tools - Tracking Products Purchased

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, authorize.net

I am looking for a third party application to report on transactions on an e-commerce site. We are looking to report on which product was purchased and the transaction amount. Each product on our site is owned by a different vendor and they would like to be able to track the history of consumer purchases of their product (as they earn money on each purchase). It would be ideal if they could have  had their own login credentials that only provide them access to see their reports.

Our application uses authorize.net as a payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Our new [ActiveReports Server](http://www.activereportsserver.com/) product includes multi-tenant support. Basically you can programmatically take over authentication by implementing a simple interface (see [ISecurityProvider](http://www.activereportsserver.com/Documentation/SDK/index.html?ActiveReports.Server.Extensibility~ActiveReports.Server.Security.ISecurityProvider_members.html)). This is how you can give a special login to each of your vendors. If you already have a login for your vendors (e.g. for a public vendor site) you can even integrate with that using the ISecurityProvider to give your vendors a single-sign-on experience.

In the documentation [here](http://www.activereportsserver.com/Documentation/AdministratorGuide/index.html?ManagingSecurityFilters.html) it explains how to configure your SecurityProvider implementation to handle authentication and how to use "Security Filters" to filter records transparently based on the logged in user. The Security Filter is how you would make sure that the vendor sees only his history.

ActiveReports Server also includes a web browser-based drag & drop ad hoc report designer powered by automatically generated and fully customizable logical data models that protect business users from underlying technical details.

```
Scott Willeke
Product Manager | ActiveReports Server
GrapeCity inc.
```